# Cmake how to add third library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am a novice in the field of CMake and I want to compile an example from OpenMVG official samples. However, I do not how to link the third library by CMake. The following is the part of the C++ file that I want to compile.

```
#include "openMVG/features/feature.hpp"
#include "openMVG/features/sift/SIFT_Anatomy_Image_Describer.hpp"
#include "openMVG/features/svg_features.hpp"
#include "openMVG/image/image_io.hpp"
#include "openMVG/image/image_concat.hpp"
#include "openMVG/matching/regions_matcher.hpp"
#include "openMVG/matching/svg_matches.hpp"
//
#include "third_party/stlplus3/filesystemSimplified/file_system.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

My CMake file is as the following.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O2 -std=c++11")
add_executable(openMVG_sample_features_siftPutative siftmatch.cpp)
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(openMVG_sample_features_siftPutative
  openMVG_image
  openMVG_features
  openMVG_matching
  Eigen3::Eigen
  ${STLPLUS_LIBRARY})
target_compile_definitions(openMVG_sample_features_siftPutative
  PRIVATE -DTHIS_SOURCE_DIR="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set_property(TARGET openMVG_sample_features_siftPutative PROPERTY FOLDER OpenMVG/Samples)
```

However, I cannot let the cmake find the file of `"third_party/stlplus3/filesystemSimplified/file_system.hpp"`. I have tried several times and I always got the error that `file_system.hpp is not found`

Comment: It seems that the file 'third_party/stlplus3/filesystemSimplified/file_system.hpp' is not in the header path space, you can find the \*\*/third_party directory in local disk, and use include_directories(\*\*) in you cmakelists.txt. Good luck

Comment: I have tried to follow your instruction. After that, however, I got a lot of errors about undefined reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like YaleCheung said, you do not have the path to your include.

Now your second problem is that you do not provide to your project the compiled-object of the method used (from the 3rdlib includes).
To fix this, as you did for the eigen3 library where you have a find_package which (certainly) defines where to find the include and the lib, you should have the equivalent for your third_party library.
So I would add:

1. include_directories (${thirdLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # I let you define this variable (could be define while the configure process)
2. and then: I think your linking problem is coming from the fact that ${STLPLUS_LIBRARY} might not contain path and lib. Try to "message()" in your cmakelists to see the content of your variable ${STLPLUS_LIBRARY}